# How to send formData to rn-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native, video, readfile, rn-fetch-blob

I'm having trouble sending large videos, the readFile method only reads small files, I tried with readStream but I didn't get a satisfactory result, with readFile if the file is smaller than 5mb it reads and sends normally to the middleware. I currently use the 'rn-fetch-blob' library.

```
   const base64 = await fs.readFile(gravacao.videoMediaFile, "base64");

   let formdata = {
     codUsuario : gravacao.codUsuario,
     codCadeiaCustodia : gravacao.codCadeiaCustodia,
     videoTamanho : gravacao.videoTamanho,
     videoMimeType : gravacao.videoMimeType,
     videoNome: gravacao.videoNome,
     gravacao.videoBase64 = base64;
   };

   console.log("form data - " + formdata);

   let response = await this.api.postMiddleware(this.api.middlewareBase + "registrar", formdata);
```

I get it in the middleware like this.

```
export async function salvar(obj) {
    
    var fs = require('fs');
    
    try{
        fs.writeFile(`./videos/video.mp4`, obj.videoBase64, 'base64', function (err){
             console.log(err);
        });

        console.log('mudou nome video');

    } catch(err){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    }

    return await ColetaAssistidaModel.create(obj);
};
```

I need to send videos of an average of 30mb for the middleware to receive and save in a folder and then send by fetch.